# Wordpress theme not following same template hierarchy when online

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a Wordpress theme.

I have made a custom post type, works, which has it's own template files: archives-works and single-works.

It is working beautifully when on localhost but online Wordpress cannot find the single-works and turns to the category template instead of archives-works.

Do You have any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question: have you uploaded your files to the remote server?

Comment: I have :)

The theme is on the server and everything is looking shiny.

Comment: Same Database? You uploaded or downloaded so you are working on the same version/s?

Comment: No - I am not using the same database remote and local. I have my dummy data local and the only thing moving is the theme folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the template hierarchy the correct name for your file should be `archive-$posttype.php` so change your `archives-works.php` in `archive-works.php`

Learn more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview

Answer (score 0):

Try using archive-works instead of archives-works